# loading page fragment in an iframe

Tags: html, iframe, page-fragments

Trying to load a page fragment, or at least jump to a div but with no joy.

```
<iframe src="http://myurl.com/#property_details" width="300" height="300">  

    </iframe>
```

but the iframe does not skip to the requested div, it simple loads the whole page, scrolled to the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think its possible to do it in such way. Another possibility to do this is using a div of which the content is set to the #property_details by using an Ajax call.

This could maybe help: http://frinity.blogspot.com/2008/06/load-remote-content-into-div-element.html. In the example the whole html of the page is used, but a selection of what you would like to insert is possible by adding some jQuery selection over the data before.